# Async request in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Here is my store:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducerFoo from './reducers/reducer';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore() {
  return createStore(
    reducerFoo,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
  );
}
```

actions:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';    
import axios from 'axios';

export const selectTag = function(tag) {

  fetchQuestions(tag);

  return {
    type: types.SELECT_TAG,
    selectedTag: tag
  }
};

export const receiveQuestions = (json) => ({
  type: types.RECEIVE_QUESTIONS,
  questions: json
});

export const fetchQuestions = tag => {

  console.log(tag);

  let url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&site=stackoverflow ....';    
  console.log(url);

  return function(dispatch) {
    return axios.get(url).then((response) =>
      dispatch(receiveQuestions(response))
    );
  };
};
```

reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import { fetchQuestions } from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
  questions: [],
  showTagPanel: true,
  selectedTag: '...',
  tags: ['one', 'two', 'three']
};


export default function reducerFoo(state = initialState, action) {

  switch(action.type) {

    case types.SHOW_TAG_PANEL:

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        showTagPanel: true
      });

    case types.SELECT_TAG:         

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        showTagPanel: false,
        selectedTag: action.selectedTag
      });

    case types.RECEIVE_QUESTIONS:

      console.log('get it');
      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I can see `url` and the `tag` in the console:

```
export const fetchQuestions = tag => {

  console.log(tag);

  let url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&site=stackoverflow ....';    
  console.log(url);
```

But the `RECEIVE_QUESTIONS` action is not working:

```
case types.RECEIVE_QUESTIONS:
      console.log('get it');
      break;
```

Why and how can I fix it ?

**Update:** but it works if I call it from index.js:

```
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(fetchQuestions('...'));
```

**Update 2:** I think in `selectTag()` I need to use

```
dispatch(fetchQuestions(tag));
```

instead of

```
fetchQuestions(tag);
```

but I don't know how to get `dispatch()` here.

Comment: Your reducer should be pure - it shouldn't have side effects.  You should move this into your action creator, or use middleware/sagas/etc.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I have moved `fetchQuestion()` call to action (and edited question), but the problem remain.

Comment: Reducer is still invalid. It should always return a state (either old or new). So you need to remove `break;` in `case types.RECEIVE_QUESTIONS:` to fall throuh to default or return a new state.

Comment: Thanks. Fix it, but still doesn't work.

Comment: "Update: but it works if I call it from index.js" - @demas what is the expected behavior that leads you to say it's working?

Comment: @PatNeedham, I have seen 'get it' message in the console

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your most recent comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `fetchQuestions` function, you have:

```
return function(dispatch) {
  return axios.get(url).then((response) =>
    dispatch(receiveQuestions(response))
  );
};
```

However, the place you're calling the function, within `selectTag` function: `fetchQuestions(tag);` is returning

```
function(dispatch) {
  return axios.get(url).then((response) =>
    dispatch(receiveQuestions(response))
  );
};
```

But it's never being called anywhere else. So one thing you can do is instead of returning that function within `fetchQuestions`, just call the `axios.get` part within which will eventually dispatch the `receiveQuestions` action once the `get` request returns.

```
export const fetchQuestions = tag => {

  console.log(tag);

  let url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&site=stackoverflow ....';    
  console.log(url);

  return axios.get(url).then((response) =>
    dispatch(receiveQuestions(response))
  );
};
```